# Get Public IP Address for node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip

Is there any node.js module that can be used to get the public IP address of the client's computer making a request? I don't mean IPv4 or IPv6, I need the public IP like you get when you go to http://www.whatismyip.com/

I have tried `req.connection.remoteAddress;` but it doesn't return the public IP. It has to be public so I can locate the city based on the IP address.

Thanks :)

Comment: http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-get-ip-address.html

Comment: when I used var ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress; inside http.createServer(function(req,res) {}); it says TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'header'. Is what you sent me in the link outdated???

Comment: That way doesn't show an IP, it just gives an error

Comment: I keep getting the IPv4

Comment: IPv4 is the public address, and it's what's shown at your link. what exactly are you expecting, can you post an example of a desired value?

Comment: I get an address like 192.168.... which is what shows up next to my IPv4 address when i run 'ipconfig' which doesn't work with the module I'm using. When I go to whatismyip.org I get an address like 99.245..... which 100% works with my application

Comment: you should only see 192.168... if your server is running locally, in which case the "call" never leaves your LAN, and you have no public IP. if you run it from, say, a VPS somewhere, you should see the same thing your link sees. indeed, a real server cannot normally see anything on an 192.168 IP...

Answer (score 1):

```
var ip = (req.headers && req.headers['x-forwarded-for'])
         || req.ip 
         || req._remoteAddress 
         || (req.connection && req.connection.remoteAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

The next line should be enough

```
let ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress;
```

If you are testing locally you will see the private IP, but if you test on the cloud the IP that you will receive is the public.

You can test it locally using `ngrok`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a packaged called external-ip that can do that for you va `npm install external-ip`:

```
var externalip = require('external-ip');
externalip(function (err, ip) {
   console.log(ip); // => 8.8.8.8
});
```

(sources: https://www.npmjs.org/package/external-ip, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24608249/823548)

Comment: I saw that module but I am not trying to find the public ip of the server computer, I'm trying to get it for the client's computer