# How to get ip in socket io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

```
var app = require("express")();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var requestIp = require('request-ip');
server.listen(3000);

var ipMiddleware = function(req, res) {
    return requestIp.getClientIp(req);
};

var ip = null;
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   ip = ipMiddleware(req, res);
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
   // send the ip to user
});
```

My problem is, I would like to get ip address of client with express and emit the ip address to client, ips are the different ones then it should be, how can I emit the ip I get with express ? thank you

Comment: try `socket.request.connection.remoteAddress`

Comment: @laggingreflex is there a possibility that I get remote adress null ? thank you for your answer

Comment: [Try one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477206/get-public-ip-address-for-node-js-application/26478095#26478095) (note, `req` ≈ `socket.request`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use something like this . I am using a `socket.io` method to get the client ip address here .

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    socket.emit('eventName',{ip : clientIp}); //emit it back to client
});
```

check this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458083/get-the-clients-ip-address-in-socket-io) to know how to get client ip for different `socket.io` versions .