# In express app/firebase functions use the original request in another request

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase function that does one thing, but I want to use the api of another service within my app, namely **ipify**, which gets the public IP of the user.

If the function is hosted on Firebase, it wouldn't make sense to call the **ipify** api directly because it would just return the public IP of the Firebase server. What am I doing wrong and is it possible to attach the client's original `req` information to the request to **ipify**?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.all('*', function(req, res) {

  req.get({url: 'https://api.ipify.org', headers: req.headers}); // This doesn't work
  // How to route a request to ipify?

  return res.status(200).send('help :(');

})
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273128/how-to-get-my-external-ip-address-with-node-js

Comment: Try dumping the contents of `req.headers` and see if what you're looking for is already in there, since that's what's coming from the client, augmented by Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I had done that before but I didn't look closely enough. I can see now that CloudFlare was changing some of the important values so I was confused why they weren't matching the IP I expected! If anyone stumbles upon this and is using CloudFlare, check the header `cf-connecting-ip`.